# How to resolve the memory issue with Map on iOS 6

Tags: memory-management, ios6, crash, mapkit

I have created an app on iOS 6 in which I am showing the Map. The problem is there is a highly increase in memory allocation in just a simple interaction with the map i.e., on Pinch and Pan and dragging operations. I thought there may be some enhancements in the Mapkit in iOS 6 which I don't know so I tried the [Sample Code of Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial) but still I am facing the same issue. Please take a look on the image I have attached. I just dragged the map for sometime and there is an allocation of 55MB. I have tested this on Simulator but on the Device, app crashes very soon. Please provide some help in any way in this regard!

[image]

Comment: How are you creating / allocating the Map view?

Answer (score 0):

From what it appears, this issue seem to only affect iOS 6 maps when dragging and zooming. There have been various hot fixes that have been proposed to address this issue. However, it appears that this is a bug that will need to be addressed by Apple.

There have been solutions proposed in this question: [iOS6 MKMapView using a ton of memory, to the point of crashing the app, anyone else notice this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641658/ios6-mkmapview-using-a-ton-of-memory-to-the-point-of-crashing-the-app-anyone-e)

Edit:
Some additional questions on stackoverflow claiming this issue.

1. [Guide to acceptable "Live Bytes" of iOS6 app using MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340999/guide-to-acceptable-live-bytes-of-ios6-app-using-mkmapview)
2. [MKMapView memory usage steadily increasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904990/mkmapview-memory-usage-steadily-increasing)
3. [Memory usage of MKMapView is very high](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982924/memory-usage-of-mkmapview-is-very-high)