# MKMapView Memory issue in iOS 6.0 or later

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Is IOS 6.0 takes more memory for `MKMapview` while zooming/dragging in IOS app, than `MKMapview` used in `ios5.0` or 5.1?

It give me memory warning while zooming `mkmapview` in `ios6.0`

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation> )annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        ((MKUserLocation *)annotation).title = kCurrentLocation;
        return nil;
    }
    
    if (annotation == self.calloutAnnotation)
    {
        CalloutMapAnnotationView *calloutMapAnnotationView=nil;
        
        if (calloutMapAnnotationView==nil){
            calloutMapAnnotationView = (CalloutMapAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"];
            calloutMapAnnotationView = [[CalloutMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"];
            
            UIImageView *calloutImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,285,109)];
            calloutImageView.image = [UIImage loadImageFromBundle:@"map-pop"];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView addSubview:calloutImageView];
            [calloutImageView bringSubviewToFront:calloutMapAnnotationView];
            
            CGRect frame1,btnframe,btnframe2;
            int font1;
            
            frame1 = CGRectMake(14,10,270,35);
            //frame for subitle label of map annotation view.
            btnframe = CGRectMake(12,53,80,25);
            btnframe2= CGRectMake(btnframe.size.width+20,btnframe.origin.y,btnframe.size.width+35, btnframe.size.height);
            font1 = 14.0;
            
            calloutMapAnnotationView.calloutTitleLabel=nil;
            calloutMapAnnotationView.calloutTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame1];
            calloutMapAnnotationView.calloutTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
            calloutMapAnnotationView.calloutTitleLabel.layer.cornerRadius=6;
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.calloutTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:font1]];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.calloutTitleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.calloutTitleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            
            calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage loadImageFromBundle:@"blank-btn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton setTitle:kInfo forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [[calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton titleLabel ]setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:font1-1]];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton.frame = btnframe;
            calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton.exclusiveTouch = YES;
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchCancel];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView addSubview:calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton bringSubviewToFront:calloutMapAnnotationView];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView addSubview:calloutMapAnnotationView.calloutTitleLabel];
            //            infoButton=nil;
            
            calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];//inDark
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage loadImageFromBundle:@"blank-btn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton.frame = btnframe2;
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton setTitle:kRouteDraw forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [[calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton titleLabel ]setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:font1-1]];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton.exclusiveTouch = YES;
            calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton.tag = well_ID;
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showRouteView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchCancel];
            [calloutMapAnnotationView addSubview:calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton];
            
        }
        
        calloutMapAnnotationView.calloutTitleLabel.text = self.titleStr;
        
        NSLog(@"well id---%d",well_ID);
        calloutMapAnnotationView.infoButton.tag = well_ID;
        
        int locationId=[[resultDict objectForKey:@"uid"] intValue];
        
        if(well_ID!=locationId)
        {
            calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton.hidden = NO;
            calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton.tag = well_ID;
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton bringSubviewToFront:calloutMapAnnotationView];
        }else{
            calloutMapAnnotationView.routeButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        calloutMapAnnotationView.parentAnnotationView = self.selectedAnnotationView;
        calloutMapAnnotationView.mapView = mapView;
        
        return calloutMapAnnotationView;
    } else {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"Pin";
        MKAnnotationView* pin = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: defaultPinID];
        int annotationValue =[annotation_array indexOfObject:annotation];
        NSString * searchLocationTitle= [annotation title];
        if ( pin == nil ) {
            pin = (MKAnnotationView*) [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier: defaultPinID];
            pin.image = [UIImage loadImageFromBundle:@"logo"];
        }
        pin.canShowCallout = NO;
        if (annotationValue!=0) {
            if([searchLocationTitle isEqualToString:kCurrentLocation])
            {
                pin.image=nil;
                
            }
            else if([searchLocationTitle isEqualToString:kSearchedLocation])
            {
                pin.image=nil;
                
            }
            else
            {
                if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
                    pin.frame = CGRectMake(-15, 0, 40,65);
                } else
                {
                    pin.frame = CGRectMake(-15, 0, 45,70);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            return nil;
        }
        return pin;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Above code for `viewForannotation` delegate method of `mkmapView`.

Comment: Explain your issue clearly. r u getting memory warning while zooming in ? if yes place that code.

Comment: the map view uses inadequate amounts of memory for ANY operation and is IMO unmanageable if you use serveral mapviews

Comment: @Ganapathy :Please see above code.It give memory warning.

Comment: Daij-Djan words may be true. Just once try with @autoreleasepool. It will handle memory leak if its with in 50MB...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### since 6+ map views use vector kit, in 4/5 it uses google maps

I must tell you that the MKMapView in ios6+ is really really bad. we spent WEEKS getting it to consume less memory but the new vector kit uses memory like crazy :/

show the whole world -- boom 50mb, show cupertino + 30, go to la + 30 go to washington DC + 30 or so...

nothing todo.. oh there's things you can try to make it better but uulimately the problem remains. **The map view is unmanageable** and we switched to the google maps sdk.

---

#### things we did before we switched (that helped):

- we shared one map view across multiple screens. We had a MKMapViewWrapperView
  that helped a lot because a map view actually 'leaks' when it is deallocated, so we always kept it around
- we sometimes toggled the mapType... that *it sounds weird) causes the map view to free some of its memory

Comment: we really tried for a long time but especially 3gs devices were not possible to manage.

Comment: did you end up using google maps instead then? And did you find it more performant? I'm running in to issues where my app's getting terminated in the background and an MKMapView is by far the biggest contributor to dirty data

Comment: Still issue is still present in iOS 9!

Answer (score 0):

I have identified that memory leaks when it occurred , when ever you have set `MKmapview` type is hybrid. That type of memory leaks  occurred.

My advice is simply select satellite

Comment: Memory leaks like crazy with satellite too, but less so than with hybrid.

Comment: Is it actually leaking? I assume hybrid is using satellite tiles overlaid with vector tiles, so it wouldn't surprise me if it uses more memory, but using memory != leaking memory. In my tests with `MKMapView` (using standard mode, not hybrid/satellite) it does have a habit of leaving its textures in memory after the `MKMapView` deallocates, but the next `MKMapView` that's allocated will clean up the old tiles before it starts generating its own new tiles.